# How Do I Install Python Libraries in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to install beautiful soup in Visual Studio, but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit:** Friend Sent me this video. Was able to install beautiful soup. I am all set now.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KY1GEOo3qy0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If you are, please enumerate them. If you aren't getting errors, what about it isn't working? Have you restarted VS?

Comment: I have restarted VS. I am honestly finding the sites I have been to confusing on which window you do the installation on. I updated pip in the Python Environments window, and wrote "pip install beautifulsoup4" in the Python interactive window. From that I got the error:

Comment: File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_repl.py", line 654, in run_one_command
    self.execute_item()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_repl.py", line 628, in execute_code_work_item
    code = compile(self.current_code, '<stdin>', 'single', self.code_flags)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install beautifulsoup4
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Which led me to assume I am not in the right window. I also tried manually downloading all the beautiful soup files and adding the folder to the Python lib folder. That also did not work.  I also tried using the Package Manager Console, but that did not recognize pip.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already fixed your problem, but you might still want to try [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

To download Anaconda go [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_windows). It contains MANY packages for python and supports 3.x and 2.x.

It is also quite easy to install more packages with Anaconda as shown [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html).

I hope this helps!